# User Interface depend on iPhone version

Tags: iphone, ios, user-interface

The question is how to tell system which UI (images , custom buttons, and so on) to show (i must to have some copies with a lower resolution and other copies with better resolution ), because iphone 3gs has a lower resolutin than iphone 4. UI of app should look greate on both devices. How can i get that ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone - adapt images to retina display](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331889/iphone-adapt-images-to-retina-display)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the [Resource Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/ImageSoundResources/ImageSoundResources.html) section called **Specifying High-Resolution Images in iOS** in the **Image, Sound, and Video Resources** chapter.

Answer (score 2):

Your non-retina images should be called `image.png` (where image is your specific filename). The retina versions should be called `image@2x.png`. The correct one will automatically be selected.