# How to name graphic files for iPad 3

Tags: ios, ipad

As I understad in iOS we can named our file for retina display as name@2x.png.

How to name file for iPad 3

ipad.png - iPad, iPad 2

ipad@2x.png - iPad 3

Is this correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is correct.

Any image for Retina display should have "`@2x`" as part of the file name.

And if you have images that are different between iPhone and iPad (as iBrad mentions), you can add "~ipad" or "~iphone" differentiators to the name. [Look at the "Updating Your Image Resource files" section of this Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/SupportingHiResScreens/SupportingHiResScreens.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH15-SW8).

Apple does have some ["Custom Icon & Image Creation Guidelines"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html) that you can look through for more details, including a section named ["Tips for Creating Great Artwork for the Retina Display."](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW16)

Also, [here is a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331889/iphone-adapt-images-to-retina-display) that talks about how to adapt your images for retina display.

Comment: He is asking for iPad 3 specifically so it should be something like: myImage@2x~ipad.png