# I need some information about @2x UIImageViews

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, retina-display

Just wanna know, how do I must use this ?

Do I just have to set @2x after the image name ? Or to put it in a specific folder ? Or something else ?

Thanks for your advices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just after the name of the file. For example name your splash 320x480 default.png and then your 640x960 default@2x.png

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is add a second image into your project, named the same as the original, exactly twice as large, with @2x at the end of the file name before the extension.

Example:

some-picture.png is 20x40 pixels

some-picture@2x.png is 40x80 pixels

Anytime you use the `imageNamed:` method, just pass the original name, like `[UIImage imageNamed:@"some-picture.png"]`

Same goes when using Interface Builder.

It will automatically choose the right one at runtime.

Comment: And the iOS device will select it by default if it's able to display 640x960px, right ?

Answer (score 1):

[I just answered another question along these same lines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10769687/981049).

Apple actually describes the expected filename in detail in the ["Updating Your Image Resource Files" section of this iOS Drawing reference guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/SupportingHiResScreens/SupportingHiResScreens.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH15-SW8).

Specifically, look for these lines in the documentation:

```
Standard: <ImageName><device_modifier>.<filename_extension>

High resolution: <ImageName>@2x<device_modifier>.<filename_extension>
```